# Split string to struct using Elixir and Regex

Tags: regex, elixir

I need parse string "Hello world (elixir is awesome) [S03E06]"
to list ["Hello world", "elixir is awesome", "S03E06"]

Help me build regex for this please.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: not exact but `/[\w\s]+/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one: `/(.*)\W+\((.*)\)\W+\[(.*)\]/`

https://regex101.com/r/hF0yD9/1